# Asp Net bundles serving HTTPS server fonts over HTTP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, font-awesome

I have a site working fine on debug over http, and refusing to load fonts on remote release over https.

Both safari and mozilla are blocking fonts, font-awesome etc: they managed to load fonts with a 302 result (Found) then just do not display as IIS server replies with headers location starting with "*http*" and not "*https*".
Mozilla describes this as "**Blocked loading mixed active content “http://yoursite.com/”**"

**EDIT:** not bundles are causing this.. included a special font.css apart from bundles via rel="stylesheet", reading fonts inside via

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings Regular';
    src: url('fonts/glyphicons.halflings.pro/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
..
```

and still have this issue..

[image]

[image]

Totally lost should i dig in IIS settings or it is ASP bundle mechanism that is causing this..

Answer (score 0):

Its a browser security restriction. If you're serving an https site, then all of your site resources should also be served over https - otherwise there is a possibility of insecure content being served.

You need to change your assets to serve over https.

See this article for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Comment: I have do not have "http" anywhere in my files, everything is relative path. If you look at the second picture you will see that fonts are requested over https from the css, it is asp created bundles redirect that is causing the problem. i even included a https rewrile rule for everything in the webconfig but still..

Comment: @NickKovalsky looking at the images, check your plugins. Bundling wouldn't have anything to do with it (if it's all relative). A plugin maybe the culprit (likely) with some `@import`

Comment: @nick Just explaining why its failing, I cant really help any further without more info.

Comment: yep in the css its @font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0'); etc

Comment: If you're using font awesome (i.e. not your own files) you could just use a free CDN link. They offer their own: https://fontawesome.com/get-started